# fade in and out from right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fadeIn from left to right and right to left to make something like this:

[image]

this is my code, but this doesn't work:

```
$(lastSlide).animate({ width: 'toggle', height:'340', opacity: 'toggle' }, "slow");
```

this is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you get the distortion by reducing the width of the image. Try to wrap the image in the div:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="img1">
    <img src="..."/>
  </div>
  <div id="img2">
    <img src="..."/>
  </div>
 </div>

 $("#img2").animate({ width: 'toggle', height:'340', opacity: 'toggle' }, "slow");
```

Simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/12x4cauv/

Comment: there's the straight line showing up in what you did, the clean edge, it should be something like, faded edge, did you see the gif above in the question?

Comment: @Prakash I think this is a really great answer. You shouldn't expect people to do all the work for you. This answer should point you on the right direction.

Comment: @Prakash 1) Upgrade your original question to have understood all the problems; 2) This is not a problem to add a semitransparent edge - try it yourself.

Comment: No, i mean, this is not what I was asking, the question is misunderstood what I am telling is, how to get that fade, okay let me look for that